# How to remove multiple background border on RecyclerView adapter in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, gridlayoutmanager, recyclerview-layout

I am using RecyclerView with Implementing GridLayoutManager spanCount 3 and issue is background border displayed multiple time see screen shot and layout. But i need to single border shape with row item on this adapter. So share your experience and Thanks in Advance!

[image]

And this is RecyclerView.Adapter row xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linSubCat"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/shape_sub_category"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/subcategory_image_listview"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subcategory_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/category_color" /></LinearLayout>
```

And Background border shape_sub_category.xml file.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke
    android:width="0.5dp"
    android:color="@color/category_color" />
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /></shape>
```

Comment: just remove the drawable background give margin/padding to 2 or 3dp and background color gray

Comment: Please post your answer by code.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: OKAY fine. !!!!

Comment: Can you post the expected output image ?

Comment: @ADM Background Border issue is displaying multiple time.

Comment: Are you saying that border is overlapping at adjacent edges ? Or Background Image ?

Comment: Yes.. Border is overlapping. So how can i solve.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ItemDecoration

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html

https://gist.github.com/lapastillaroja/858caf1a82791b6c1a36

[Refer Here](https://bignerdranch.github.io/simple-item-decoration/#grid_divider_item_decoration)

sample

```
int numColumns = 2;

Drawable horizontalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.divider_horizontal);
Drawable verticalDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.divider_vertical);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(..., numColumns));

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridDividerItemDecoration(horizontalDivider, verticalDivider, numColumns));
```

Horizontal:divider_horizontal.xml

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#FF0000" />
```

Vertical:divider_vertical.xml

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000" />
```

Comment: Please Give me divider_horizontal & divider_vertical shape code.

Comment: Need drawable xml file not a layout xml view code. Give me other solution.